# How to show negative values in an NDVI image?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing, earthpy

I am fairly new to python. I am working with some Landsat 8 .tiff images to produce an NDVI image. When I produce the image, the river does not show as a negative value. NDVI goes from -1 to 1, but the lowest it goes to is 0 in this image. This is a portion of the code I used:

```py
import os
from glob import glob

import sys
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap  
import rasterio as rio 
from rasterio.plot import plotting_extent 
import rioxarray as rxr
import geopandas as gpd 
import earthpy as et  
import earthpy.spatial as es  
import earthpy.plot as ep
```

```
#create image stack
arr_st, meta = es.stack(stack_bands_path, nodata = -9999)

#allow division by 0
np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')

#create NDVI
red = arr_st[3].astype(float)
nir = arr_st[4].astype(float)

ndvi = np.divide((nir-red), (nir+red))
ep.plot_bands(ndvi, cmap="RdYlGn", cols=1, vmin=-1, vmax=1)
plt.show()
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I was originally using earthpy.spatial.normalized_difference but the rivers were coming out green (or 1 on the colorbar).

My theory is that the numbers less than 0 are showing up as zero...but I am not sure. Any help is appreciated. Image of the NDVI is below.

[image: NDVI image]

Comment: Test this: print(np.all(nir>=red))

Comment: It says "False." That means there are nor NIR values greater than or equal to red....which means I should be getting negative NDVI values, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NDVI will fall in the range `-1` to `+1` so an integer is not a good representation because there are only 3 possible integer outcomes in that range, namely -1, 0 and 1.

I am not familiar with the specific package you are using but, if you want fractional (decimal) results, I would imagine you'd want to use the `float` type, i.e.:

```
red = arr_st[3].astype(float)
nir = arr_st[4].astype(float)
```

Comment: I tried that, but it still does not show any negative values. Thanks anyways.

Comment: You haven't provided a *"Minimum Complete Verifiable Example"* with `import` statements and representative images so it's harder to help you. Try checking `ndvi.min()` and `ndvi.max()` to see the range of your data before display. Bear in mind that PNG format cannot store negative values. Try rescaling your data to the range 0..255 by doing `ndvi=((ndvi+1)*127).astype(np.uint8)`

Comment: Ahh, I see! Sorry. I did end up thinking of doing the max and min, and it came out to be 6673 and -1. I did np.max(ndvi) since I am using numpy. I am also working with tiff files. I edited my question to include the import statements.

Comment: You've gone wrong if your `max` exceeds 1. There are no values for `a` and `b` such that `(a-b)/(a+b) > 1`.

Comment: Yes, I am aware.